# A post apocalyptic movie seen mid 80s; man and mechanical companion

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think I saw this on the BBC around the late 1970's or early 1980's   I recall a main character (Jack?) who had as a machine companion (on a walking stick of course) being pursued by (Renault???) who is trying to kill him/them.

Near the end, the main character jumps into a ravine (or similar) to avoid being killed but cant get the companion (on a stick) in time and he is blown up...

I sort of recall this might have been during a pledge break or saturnday morning on BBC?

Live action.

The companion was an intelligent machine (part of a much larger machine)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't post your e-mail address or other personal information.

Comment: I think this might be related to this (unanswered) question. It gives a few more details https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/lone-fighter-in-a-post-apocalyptic-world-with-ai-companion-on-a-stick?r=SearchResults

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Was he wearing sword or katana ?